# CTE Update taking forever

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a temporary table with random hostnames populated as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #strings_temp (
stringtemp VARCHAR(30));

-- Create a temporary table with random strings with the same row count as table 2  
DECLARE @row INT;
DECLARE @TotalRows INT;
SET @row = 0;
SET @TotalRows = (Select DISTINCT COUNT(*) From table2) 

WHILE @row <= @TotalRows
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #strings_temp
(stringtemp)
   select char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
   +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
   +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
   +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
   +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+ 
   + '.' 
   +char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)+char(rand()*26+65)
                    +'.' + 'RANDOM.COM';
   SET @row = @row + 1;
 END;
```

I then want to use a CTE to update a value in table 2 with data from the temporary table as follows but it is taking a huge amount of time:

```
-- Update the string field with the string from the temporary table

WITH Table2CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
            stringname,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) 
    FROM table2
)
, SampleStringData AS
(
    SELECT  
             stringtemp,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM #strings_temp

    CROSS JOIN Table2CTE
)
UPDATE m
SET      m.stringname = fn.stringtemp
FROM Table2CTE AS m

INNER JOIN SampleStringData AS fn
    ON fn.rn = m.rn
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: how many rows are we talking about here?  Are you sure it's the CTE that's taking all the time, and not the loop population of the temporary table?

Comment: 42,000 rows. The loop population takes seconds when tested.

Comment: `FROM #strings_temp CROSS JOIN Table2CTE` that's gotta be a whole lot of rows, no?

Comment: I think you're right! I've just tested and it's a lot of rows.

Comment: I've removed it and it's fixed! I had copied the query from another script that I needed the cross join for. Thanks!

Comment: Now taking a few seconds to run.

Answer (score 1):

Removed CROSS JOIN and now fixed

```
-- Update the string field with the string from the temporary table

WITH Table2CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
           stringname,
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) 
    FROM table2
)
, SampleStringData AS
(
    SELECT  
             stringtemp,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM #strings_temp
)
UPDATE m
SET      m.stringname = fn.stringtemp
FROM Table2CTE AS m

INNER JOIN SampleStringData AS fn
    ON fn.rn = m.rn
```